# Column not found when trying a cross database update in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1054

I'm trying to copy the contents of a column in one mysql database to an identical table in another mysql database.

I'm using:

```
UPDATE db1.table
SET    db1.table.name = db2.table.name, 
       db1.table.address = db2.table.address
WHERE  db1.table.id = db2.table.id;
```

I'm getting the error 1054: Unknown column 'db2.table.id' in 'where clause'.

Both tables have an id column, so I'm not sure why it won't work. I'm logged in as admin, and have full rights to both databases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
UPDATE db1.table
JOIN   db2.table
ON     db1.table.id = db2.table.id
SET    db1.table.name = db2.table.name, 
       db1.table.address = db2.table.address
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked precisely as I was hoping.

Comment: Note that you can use something like ON db1.table.id = db2.table.id AND db1.table.id2 = db2.table.id2 for a multi-join, as was needed in my case.
You can also use an alias like UPDATE db1.table AS tbl1 JOIN db2.table AS tbl2, and then reference just the aliases through the rest of the query for succinctness.