# Cross database update?

Tags: mysql

is it possible to 
`update proj_oct.writings set proj_oct.writings.writer_id=jozad_bkb.elx_content.writer where proj_oct.writings.id=jozad_bkb.elx_content.id` ??

it gives me `Unknown column 'jozad_bkb.elx_content.id' in 'where clause'` but it exists .

Thank you .

**Edit :**

copied the table to same database , this fails :
 `UPDATE writings SET writer_id = elx_content.writer WHERE id = elx_content.id`

Comment: copied the table to same database , this fails : `UPDATE writings SET writer_id = elx_content.writer WHERE id = elx_content.id`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column not found when trying a cross database update in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050544/column-not-found-when-trying-a-cross-database-update-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to an update/select:

```
UPDATE writings SET writer_id = select writer from elx_content WHERE writings.id = elx_content.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution :

```
update `elx_content` as x , writings as y set y.writer_id =x.writer  where y.id=x.id
```